# S3 .NET SDK Hash before upload?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

When I upload a file using S3, does the SDK hash the file and make sure the current version isn't the same before it uploads? I would like to use an MD5 function in my code but if it's already being done I don't want to waste time hashing large files twice but I also don't want to waste the time uploading a file that is already there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are referring to the AWS SDK for .NET, then no it does not currently do a check against Amazon S3 when you are uploading an object.